# Why does Steam update my game when I tell it not to?

Tags: steam

I have a game that I don't play often, and would like to not update until I actually play it. So I went into the Properties of the game and under the "Automatic updates" section changed the option to "Only update this game when I launch it." However, every time I turn on Steam, the choice is reverted back to "Always keep this game up to date," even though I didn't change anything!

I turn off my computer every night, so the Steam program does completely close each day.

My questions are:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do I stop it?

[image: The problem]

Comment: I think it works in an opposite way. You may need to disable auto updates for all games through Steam's "Downloads" settings, and then choose which games you want to auto-update. Let me know how it works out and I'll craft it into a proper answer if it does.

Comment: But I want all my games to update regularly except for this one? Then wouldn't I have to add a game to that list every time I bought a new game? And why would they have this option in the game Properties if it worked in the opposite way?

Comment: Those are good points, I was only speculating, hence it's just a comment. I'm really not sure why it would be opposite, just theorizing.

Comment: Have you tried this on games other than Dota2?

Comment: I have not. However, Steam had an update so it restarted (after I had already booted up it up and changed it to "Only update when I start the game" and I can confirm that after the Steam program restarted, the option was still the same this time.

Comment: Turn off cloud.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf – disabling automatic updates from Steam settings is no longer possible. The option has been removed in a recent update.

Comment: @DanielSaner How recent are we talking here? My comment was from August 3rd...

Comment: @Kaizerwolf About half a year, I think. I don't think the change was announced in the changelog, because I usually read those. There has been some discussion/criticism on the Steam forums, though, and those threads seem to reach back to roughly March 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue suddenly seems to have resolved itself. I continued to change the setting to "Update this game only when I launch it" each time I logged on to Steam. Suddenly the past few times I've booted up Steam it has saved the setting.

I didn't do anything differently, so I don't know what solved the issue. Maybe they patched it in one of the updates.